# Elasticsearch starts with search by using Partial Matching queries

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search for `product1`, I should only get:

```
Product1
Product1/Product1
Product1-Product
Product1\Product1
```

however I am getting these:

```
Product1
Product1/Product1
Product1-Product
Product1\Product1
Product-Product1
Product\Product1
Product Product1
```

so my example queries below run like `... name LIKE '*product1*'` instead of `... LIKE 'product1*'`. I've gone through the [Partial Matching documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/partial-matching.html) but couldn't solve the problem. The `name` field is `not_analyzed` string in mapping.

```
{"query":{"prefix":{"name":"product1"}}}

{"query":{"wildcard":{"name":"product1*"}}}

{"query":{"regexp":{"name":"product1*"}}}

{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"wildcard":{"name":"product1*"}}]}}}

{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"wildcard":{"name":"product1*"}}}}}

{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":{"regexp":{"name":"product1*"}}}}}}}
```

**My ES version** (`I know it is a bit old`):

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Hannah Levy",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include your mapping, but I suspect the mapping of `name` is something like `{"type": "string", "index": "analyzed"}` (or the equivalent `{"type": "string"}` -- the default is analyzed). The matches are on individual terms (not the raw string), and the individual terms created when `Product-Product1` is indexed with the standard analyzer, are `Product` and `Product1`. Of course `Product1` matches.

You'll have to re-index with `"index": "not_analyzed"`, or add a new field with that mapping. (Actually it looks like you may need some analysis if you want `product1` to match `Product1` -- in that case I think you want to use a custom analyzer with a keyword tokenizer and lowercase filter.)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it. It is `not_analyzed` string.

Comment: Oh that makes your question much more interesting! I'll investigate some later and update my answer if I find anything. Have you tried a query_string query?

Comment: No I haven't bevause the "query_string" doc says `Be aware that wildcard queries can use an enormous amount of memory and perform very badly`.

Comment: In mapping I had two "name" fields. One `name` analyzed and another `name.raw` not_analyzed so the problem was I was using `name`. I now use `name.raw` and it works fine. +1 for your suspicion which made me suspicious too. I looked into the mapping but it is sometimes easy to miss things like that.

Comment: Yeah, mappings are always difficult to read accurately. Anyway I'm glad you found it! I was thinking this must be some really weird 1.7 behavior and had just gotten 1.7.4 working in docker -- I will stop now, haha. :)

Comment: Now I have to find out which one would be the best as in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you must be searching for `product1*` and not `Product1.*` ? Basically you want to match any character following Product1 0 or moer times. Please read the documentation of regex used by lucene [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html?is-external=true).

PS: I tried out your use-case in kibana with my regex and it works as expected.